# If I sign a job offer while on PTO, should I give notice as soon as I sign it or when I come back to work?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, new-job, notice-period, consulting

I am not sure if I should contact HR while on PTO just to give notice.

Contractually specified notice period is three weeks. If I wait till I come back, I will be giving them notice period of three weeks.

Comment: do you have a contractually specified notice period? what is that period. If you wait till you come back how much notice will you be giving them?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Contractually specified notice period is three weeks. If I wait till I come back, I will be giving them notice period of three weeks

Comment: @xitokeh561 - Is the remaining time of your PTO off longer than a full work week? Would starting your job a week early be potentially beneficial to your economic situation? If you are on PTO that leave is obligated to you, it being part of your 3 week notice, seems to be a reasonable request. Depends on your employer’s leave policy

Comment: If you have PTO remaining then will it be factored into the 3 weeks notice?

Comment: @Donald The remaining time of my PTO is less than a full work week

Comment: @SolarMike I don't think so. Consulting services agreement says I should provide a three weeks advance notice

Comment: So you loose it - tough.

Answer (score 5):

Decide on what day you wish to leave.
Subtract three weeks.
Give your notice on that day.

Give notice to your boss first, then HR if needed.

Answer (score 1):

On the day you return from PTO, give your contractually obligated three weeks notice. Most companies will have a problem if you take significant amount of time off during the notice period. Though most don't define significant.

The notice period is to finish your current tasks, document what you do, and make yourself available to train somebody else. Though in most cases anybody you train will already be on the team, because it takes time to find a replacement, plus they might also have a notice period.

Answer (score -2):

This really depends.

For example, in India, there is a rule in *most* of the organisations, that you cannot avail / use PTO while you're in a notice period. Hence, two of the things can happen here

- You submit your resignation while you're on PTO, it will not be accepted. You'll need to re-submit when you resume work.
- Your resignation while on PTO will be accepted, but the count of notice period will start based on the date of you resuming the work

where either of these have the same *effect*, just different procedure.

Your best bet it, submit the resignation already. Best case, the'll accept the same and consider the countdown from the date of submission, worst case, the'll start the countdown once you join, or ask you to re-submit when you resume work. You got nothing to lose by submitting it right now (while you're on PTO).

Comment: The OP has just added a "US" location tag, so I'm not sure that referencing India is relevant.

Comment: That was for adding context, as example.

Comment: It's always interesting to get a perspective from other countries. And next year, someone from India may have exactly the same question.